# Is degenerate neutrino mass possible?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

Can two of the three light neutrino masses be exactly degenerate in the context of current experimental data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[2016 PDG review](http://www-pdg.lbl.gov/2016/reviews/rpp2016-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf) citing [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07777) lists $3\sigma$ allowed value for $\Delta m_{21}^2/[10^{-5} eV^2]=(6.93 - 7.97)$. Mass degeneracy would also allow to simplify PMNS matrix by making certain phases unobservable whereas they are known to be non-zero.

Comment: Both the mass square differences $\Delta m^2_{21}$ and $\Delta m^2_{23}$ have been measured to be nonzero. Doesn't that rule out the possibility of any two neutrino masses being degenerate? @OON

Comment: @SRS yep, and no one claimed that they are degenerate.